# why does my ffmpeg process wait forever without stdin parameter to subprocess.run?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I am using the python subprocess module to call ffmpeg like this:

```
def ffmpeg_wait(self, fname, args):
    ffmpeg = subprocess.run([
        'ffmpeg', '-v', 'quiet', '-i', fname, *args],
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True)
    print('terminated')
    (out,err) = (ffmpeg.stdout, ffmpeg.stderr)
    return out + err
```

This works fine. An example call:

```
self.ffmpeg_wait(fname,
    ['-r', str(sps), '-s', '320x240', '-f', 'image2', 'tmp/%06d.png'])
```

What I want to know is why it doesn't work when I omit the `stdin` parameter. In this case the *ffmpeg* process waits forever iff I start my program as a background process in the shell. Running in the foreground works.

I guess this has something to do with how the shell handles stdio channels and how they are inherited by subprocesses, but I cannot figure it out. I tried (unsuccessfully) to re-establish this behaviour in the shell (using redirection).

Any explanation or documentation pointers?

PS: *ffprobe* does not do this. It always works even without *stdin* parameter. So it's also something in *ffmpeg* which triggers this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t tell it somehow to ignore `stdin`, it expects the image itself (not just a file name) to come from `stdin`, as if you sat there and typed in the image byte by byte. This is essential to “piping” commands in *nix systems, but it means that many commands will appear to hang if you don’t explicitly direct them to some input stream other than `stdin`.

Comment: I was not aware that ffmpeg always also uses stdin. After that, finding the option and re-establishing the same behaviour in the shell was no problem. Thanks for the hint.